# No foreign_key related in validated_data in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I want to POST into my Album using my AlbumSerializer. The problem is I don't receive the Artist name in the validated data inside the function create.

```
#models.py
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    title = models.CharField()

#serializers.py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        ...
```

I am passing in this data:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "artist": "Enimem",
    ...
}
```

When I print the validated_data, the artist is not included. Is it because it is a foreign key? Then how will I add it to the validated_data?

```
{'name': 'Test', ...}
```

I have tried adding the function to_interval_value, which resolved my problem, but I really don't want it added because it messes up the default ValidationErrors.

```
def to_interval_value(self, data):
    return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `StringRelatedField` uses the `__str__` method as specified [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) and **most importantly it's read only**, so that's why.

You want to make it read-write since `read_only` means it will be used for display but ignored as an input when POSTing (see here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only).

I think you want to use read-write `SlugRelatedField` specifying `slug_field='name'` and `queryset=Artist.objects.all()`:

```py
artist = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Artist.objects.all())
```

Look at the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for more info about this.

Note that the field should be unique.

Comment: Still not in the validated_data

Comment: Could you show what is your current code with SlugRelatedField? For me that works. Remember to set queryset as well.

Comment: How to set queryset?

Comment: I only used `artist = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name')`

Comment: The problem is that you are making it `read_only` but you want it to make it write too. `read_only` means that it will be used for display only, so if you send it, it will be ignored. Remove `read_only` and add `query_set=Artist.objects.all()`, the serializer will use this queryset to validate the input. Like this: `artist = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Artist.objects.all())` I will update my answer to be more clear. In the docs this is also explained.